# Where do I find the .py files to add in my spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I work on an edgenode where some libraries like pandas, sqlalchemy which i installed manually because the proxy is too restricted.

I am trying to add those libraries to my spark job to deploy it on cluster where these libraries aren't installed, I know that I must add some parameters in order to do so

`spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --queue high --py-files filesToAdd sparkjob.py`

But I dont know which "filesToAdd" I have to put on the command line, is it the library source code? is it a specific part of it? is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add libraries with --py-files. All the libraries like `pandas`, `sqlalchemy` and others should be installed on every cluster node.

`--py-files` argument should be used to distribute your **application code** on the cluster. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html for more details